# If you delete a git branch do it's commits go with it?

Tags: git

If I create a new branch, make a few commits, and then decide, "wow, I've done nothing good here," and I delete the branch (`git branch -d branchname`) do those few commits go away too? As in, do they disappear from my git log?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commits won't show up in `git log` anymore when no branch references them, but they *will* be kept around for a while to prevent accidental loss of work. There are several safety layers:

- Commits are only ever considered for garbage collection if they are no longer *referenced*. This typically happens if only a single branch/ref had a reference to them, and you delete that ref.
- Unless configured differently, Git retains a log of old states of a branch ("*reflog*"). Reflog entries are expired eventually, subject to a configurable age threshold (two, in fact: one for reflog entries that contain stuff that's reachable from the current state of the branch, and one for stuff no longer reachable from the branch; the default for the latter is 30 days). Before this, `git gc` will keep your reflog entries there and will not delete commits still reachable via those reflog entries.
- Even if you forcibly clear your reflogs, `git gc` will still keep objects if they were created less than two weeks ago (by default; this is configurable).
- After all that, the objects are physically deleted when you run `git gc`.

To look at reflogs, try `git log -g SOMEBRANCH`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they disappear from the git log, and no, they do not disappear from the repository until the subsequent `git gc` (garbage collector) command.

You can still find those commits using the `git reflog` command.